# spring ioc and JSR168 Portlets

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, jsr168

Is it possible to do dependency injection using spring into a jsr168 Portlet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - have a look at the [portlet chapter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/portlet.html) in the spring reference.

Notice that you need to implement the [special spring portlet controller](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/portlet.html#portlet-controller) interface, and not the standard portlet. These controller as well as the injected beans should be in the spring context file specified in the contextConfigLocation parameter. I guess that the usual applicationContext.xml will work as well (if you register the spring servlet context listener)

Comment: ok cool so JSR168's portlet.xml file works kinda like a regular spring applicationContext.xml. My question however is, do i need to create a separate xml file containing the name of the Portlet class i want to inject or can i do it through the Portlet.xml file? Also, would there be a conflict if this class is created as a bean in both xml files? Thanks

Comment: I've added some info. notice that the portlet.xml is not a spring context file. You define in it a spring implementation of a portlet, which knows to delegate the requests to other beans (this is similar to web.xml and the DispatcherServlet)